# Cursors storage location in Ubuntu

Tags: cursor

Where are cursor files (`.cur`, `.ani`) as in Windows stored in Ubuntu. I want to use the Ubuntu cursors in Windows.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu (and Linux in general) uses the X11 cursor format, which isn't supported by Windows. On Ubuntu, these files are located in `/usr/share/icons/<name-of-cursor-theme>`. The default is DMZ-White.

If you want to use the DMZ cursor theme on Windows, you can use this set converted to Windows cursor format: http://nighted.deviantart.com/art/DMZ-Cursors-58429447